# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V without maven

Tags: java, selenium, testng, guava

I have an old project (selenium 2.53) and have to move it to 3.141.59.
Eclipse cannot use maven (no connection to the server)
On extern pc I set up the maven project, setted up all the libraries and moved the sources to new locaton. After some code changes was all ok.
The libraries are now in the intern network migrated.
After test run I received the good known error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource(Resources.java:208)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.onlyOverrideThisIfYouKnowWhatYouAreDoing(FirefoxProfile.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.ProfilesIni.getProfile(ProfilesIni.java:130)
    at dtr.gematik.framework.BaseTest.classLevelSetup(BaseTest.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:64)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:364)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:318)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:588)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1214)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1136)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1066)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1034)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

TestNG 7.2.0
Selenium 3.141.59
guava 29.0-jre
Error Log View show no conflicts
Problems View contains just warnings

Thanks for any help

**additional information:**

- new workspace and new project created.
- only *src/*-folder copied into new project
- added all needed deps (only new versions)
- customized the sources, so no compile errors are there
- temp-files cleaned
- `-clean` in eclipse.ini inserted (forgotten to say)

Comment: @DebanjanB is not dublicated
all libs are in the last version and I have NO MAVEN

Comment: The previous references of _guava_ of selenium 2.53 still collides with the current version of the selenium 3.141.59. Clean up your `project` workspace from your IDE and `temp` directory.

Comment: all the old libs are removed from project, just the new are copied
project was cleaned

Comment: It's not only for being copied, did you perform the steps I've mentioned above?

Comment: yes, I did all steps

Comment: Can you update the main question with the additional steps you have taken following the dup target as well as my comments?